# Having trouble getting Excel VBA code to execute consistently. First time using a collection

Tags: excel, vba

This code is used to add new rows in three fields to an existing Excel template file. The current worksheet is used to create a three column collection, that is then compared to the same list of dogs registration numbers in the template. (Dog's registration numbers are unique to only one dog, no matter what breed.) Duplicates are removed from the collection and the remaining collection is then added to the end of the existing name list in the template (although I can't figure out how to add multiple dogs in one pass but I did successfully work around that).
The major problem I'm having is what appears to be a random inconsistency in getting the data correctly into the template. The spreadsheet columns are Registration Number, Dog Registered Name and Dog Call Name. Since the current workbook is created from the template, there should be no formatting differences to contend with.
The code never returns an error message of any sort. I've tried some Debug.Print routines that show that the data from the lists do not get written correctly into the collection. I have no idea why most of them occur but did figure out that if the Registered Name and Call Name fields are identical, the collection sees that as only one data point, not two. There is only one dog in the database with that quirk, but it would be helpful if I could figure out a fix for that.
During testing, I've had the code execute successfully four or five times then put garbage into the template - by garbage I mean it would put data in the wrong fields, enter only the registration number into all three template fields, stuff like that. To maintain consistency of testing I would use the same data each time, just to be clear.
(This code is for only one breed. I have 22 breeds in the spreadsheet. I tried to write a loop but the collection kept recognizing only the first breed. I'm not looking for an answer to that at the moment but am including it in case there's something in this code that was causing that problem as well.)

I've tried the Msgbox that shows what the data being collected looks like. It looks like the problem is occurring during the building of the collection but why it works sometimes and not others is baffling me.
I tried adding Stops after each section of the code to see if that helped. I can't say it did.
I did a ton of research on the net prior to even starting this but most of the help seemed to be finding items that matched then doing something, usually in the same workbook or worksheet. So I could be missing some snippet of code that will cure the problem.
I used Debug. Print to try and figure out what is corrupting the data but was unable to fully figure out a cause. I did have a few cases where one of the For..Each statements got hung up because the list.remove If statement wasn't executing any result when it should have been.

One might ask why I simply don't copy the entire Dog By BREED sheet from the current workbook to the template and save myself some hassle. There is a lot of other programming in this spreadsheet that uses the data on the sheet. My experience with cut and paste in Excel where formulas are concerned is all negative. I don't want to have five (non-consecutive) years of work blown up.

The instructions for showing the code say to use as little as possible so I've included only what I think is pertinent. If you need to see more just ask but I think this will work.

```
'=======================================================================
'Function is to add new items to the template from the current workbook.
'===========================================================================
' Create collection from current workbook. The collection has three fields.
'===========================================================================
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
With wb1.Worksheets("Dogs by BREED")
    For Each cell In .Range("H9", .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If Not list.Contains(cell.Value) Then list.Add cell.Value
        End If
    Next
End With

 '============================================================
 'Remove matches from collection that are already in template.
 '============================================================

With wb.Worksheets("Dogs by BREED")
    For Each cell In .Range("H9", .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If list.Contains(cell.Value) Then list.Remove cell.Value
    Next
End With

 '=================================
 'Update template with new records.
 '=================================

With wb.Worksheets("Dogs by BREED")
    If list.Count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "List Count is: " & list.Count, "Lastrow is: " & lastrow
    Else
        Do Until list.Count = 0
        'MsgBox Join(list.ToArray, ", "), vbInformation, "New Data"
        lastrow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Debug.Print "List Count is: " & list.Count, "Lastrow is: " & lastrow
        wb.Worksheets("Dogs by BREED").Range("H" & lastrow, "J" & lastrow).Value = list.ToArray
        For Each cell In .Range("H9", .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If list.Contains(cell.Value) Then list.Remove cell.Value
        Next
        Loop
    End If
End With
    list.Clear
    Set list = Nothing
```

Data from the current workbook.

```
Reg Number  Registered Name Call Name
HM55217902  DC Apu Must be the Money    Trill
HM79741005  FC Thor's East Of Midnight MC LCX4  Midnight
HM85885107  FC Thor's Painter Passing Thru MC   Girlfriend
HM92957602  FC Apu Occhi Belli  Occhi
HP03103402  CH Kisa N' Akuba's Muddy Sneakers   Rhubarb
HP08021401  DC Ahmahr Nahr's El Cerro Ranger JC Jake
HP11484805  Whimsical Mystical Nickel   Nickel
```

Data from the template.

```
Reg Number  Registered Name Call Name
HM55217902  DC Apu Must be the Money    Trill
HM79741005  FC Thor's East Of Midnight MC LCX4  Midnight
HM85885107  FC Thor's Painter Passing Thru MC   Girlfriend
HM92957602  FC Apu Occhi Belli  Occhi
```

Expected result is that the last three rows of data are copied to the template.
Some actual results are:
The Reg Number was copied into all three fields in the template.
The Reg Number was omitted and the Registered Name was copied into the Reg Number field, and the Call Name into the Registered Name field. Any time a field was missing in the collection it becomes an issue that is not error trapped.

Comment: What you've posted seems like an odd way to approach this, and it could be done with much less code.  Loop over the cells in the first column of the source dataset and use Match or Find to see if the reg number already exists on the destination sheet - if it does not then copy the source row over.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would do the job:

```
Dim cell As Range, v, rngTarget As Worksheet

With wb.Worksheets("Dogs by BREED")
    Set rngTarget = .Range(.Range("H9"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
End With

With wb1.Worksheets("Dogs by BREED")
    For Each cell In .Range(.Range("H9"), _
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = cell.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            'is there a match in the target sheet?
            If IsError(Application.Match(v, rngTarget, 0)) Then
                'no match, so copy over
                cell.Resize(1, 3).Copy _
                     rngTarget.Cells(rngTarget.Cells.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                'add a row to the target range
                Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Resize(rngTarget.Cells.Count + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: I got it to work with a couple of changes. Thanks much for your help.